# How to calculate a threshold percentage

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a %threshold using the ZN function in tableau on the attached example:

1) work out absolute difference of converted net money split by jacket portfolio e.g. for jacket portfolio A it would be equal to 1,517,578 (|-5,067,557+3,549,979|)

2) divide the answer in step 1 by the 8,617,536 to get a %threshold (17.61%) e.g. 1,517,578/8,617,536

**Sample Data**
[image]

Comment: Can you share the data in excel or TWBX format ?

Comment: you need to use `windows_sum` for these kind of calculations, you need to provide more details or attach workbook